# What's the difference between "auto v = f()" and "auto&& v = f()"?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, perfect-forwarding, type-deduction

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<int> f()
{
    return{};
}

// Update: Below is not compilable
void g(vector<int>)
{}

// Update: Below is the my initial intent.
/*
void g(const vector<int>&)
{}
*/

void g(vector<int>&&)
{}

int main()
{
    auto       v1 = f();
    auto&& v2 = f();

    g(forward<vector<int>>(v1));
    g(forward<vector<int>>(v2));
}
```

Does C++11 guarantee `g(forward<vector<int>>(v1))` will call `f(vector<int>)` or `f(const vector<int>&)` and `g(forward<vector<int>>(v2))` will call `f(vector<int>&&)`?

Comment: This doesn't compile on my machine. Call to g() is ambiguous. So the question actually should be why that happens.

Comment: I strongly suggest reverting the edit, your change renders existing answers invalid. Or perhaps post an addendum in the edit, without changing the original code

Comment: @M.M, Updated the post as you suggested.

Comment: The last paragraph could also do with an edit (as well as the type change, you wrote `f` where you mean `g`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that `v1` is a vector while `v2` is an rvalue reference to a vector.

Overloading `g` the way you have done is a very bad idea. If the argument is a cv-unqualified rvalue, then the call will be ambiguous since both `g`'s can accept the rvalue with the identity conversion sequence. It is, however, acceptable to have one overload take `T&` and the other take `T&&`.

If you want to forward the value category of `f()`, don't copy/move it as you have done into `v1`. That destroys the value category information. `v1` will always be an lvalue.

Besides, you are not using `std::forward` properly. Both `v1` and `v2` will be cast to rvalue reference, and would behave the same way under overload resolution in that case.

Here is what the proper usage of `std::forward` looks like:

```
void g(vector<int>&);
void g(vector<int>&&);
int main() {
    auto&& v1 = function_returning_lvalue_vector();
    auto&& v2 = function_returning_rvalue_vector();
    g(forward<decltype(v1)>(v1));  // calls lvalue overload
    g(forward<decltype(v2)>(v2));  // calls rvalue overload
}
```

Comment: _v2 is an rvalue reference_ ...actually it's not, see answer of M.M.

Comment: @zett42 In defence of this answer - saying "`v2` is..." is ambiguous;  v2 *the entity* is an rvalue reference, but v2 *the expression* is an lvalue.  I agree that the first paragraph could be cleared up a bit as it won't make much sense to someone who doesn't understand that distinction.

Answer (score 2):

There is an object associated with a return-by-value function called the *return value*. The return value of `f()` is a `vector<int>`.

In C++11 and C++14, where `f()` returns by value:

- `auto v1 = f();` initializes a `vector<int>`, which will be known as `v1`, from the return value, using the copy/move constructor. This is a copy elision context.
- `auto&& v2 = f();` makes the name `v2` designate the return value, and the return value's lifetime is extended.

If the compiler does implement copy-elision then these two codes have the same effect. From C++17, with the so-called "guaranteed copy elision", these two codes will be the same.

By "the same", I mean the same in all respects except for the result of `decltype(identifier)` as discussed below.

---

There is no difference between your two `g` calls. In both cases, the argument is an lvalue of type `std::vector`. The *expressions* `v1` and `v2` do not "remember" whether they were originally a return value object or not.

`std::forward` is only useful when given a template parameter that is the result of perfect forwarding deduction (therefore, may be a reference type).

It was suggested to use `decltype`. `decltype(identifier)` is a special case that does recall how the *identifier* was declared, after `auto` deduction has been applied.

- `decltype(v1)` is `vector<int>`
- `decltype(v2)` is `vector<int> &&`

But now we have:

- `std::forward<decltype(v1)>` is `vector<int> &&`
- `std::forward<decltype(v2)>` is `vector<int> &&`

So you still do not distinguish the two different forms of `g`.

In fact, as noted in comments, it is not possible to call `g` at all. Every call will be ambiguous. In overload resolution, direct reference binding is an identity conversion; an xvalue argument of type `T` is an equal match for parameter `T` as for `T&&`.  (Similarly, an lvalue argument of type `T` would be an equal match for parameter `T` as for `T&`).

It would be possible to overload `g` to have lvalue vs. rvalue overloads. But you'd need to make changes to `v1`'s initialization too:

```
void g(vector<int> const &) {}
void g(vector<int> &&) {}

// ...
auto const& v1 = f();
auto&& v2 = f();

g( std::forward<decltype(v1)>(v1) );
g( std::forward<decltype(v2)>(v2) );
```

Comment: So far so good, but why is the call to g() ambiguous? It is not ambigous anymore if I remove forward(). Then the first overload will always be called, as expected.

Comment: @zett42 rvalue of type `T` is equal match for `T` as `T&&`

Comment: But shouldn't forward() return an lvalue reference?

Comment: @zett42 `forward<T>` only gives an lvalue if `T` is an lvalue reference type. Otherwise it gives an xvalue

Comment: I see, forward doesn't work as intended here because the type was explicitly given to forward. So it simply returns an rvalue of that type, just as any regular function would do.

Comment: Maybe add this as a "useful" example where std::forward actually works as intended: `template<typename T> void h(T&& v) { g(std::forward<T>(v)); }` ... you would have to change the first overload to `void g(const vector<int>&)` then, to be able to call h() with rvalue...

Comment: @zett42 Well that's the canonical use of `forward` that would be found on any documentation of `forward`.  But OP's code can still never call that version of `g` if he is using `std::forward`.